# How to use regex to find values that may be interspersed with spaces

Tags: regex, r

Let's say I have a string that normally looks like this:

`goodString <- "RPT#            AMT:123.45            CUR:USD       TRDR#"`

Using regular expressions and the `stringr` package, I can extract the value I need out of the string by simply passing this code:

`amount <- str_extract(goodString, "(?<=AMT:)\\S+")`

However, let's say we have anomalies like this:

`badString <- "RPT#            AMT: 1, 234.5 6            CUR:USD       TRDR#"`

How do I extract the value 1,234.56 from that string when the spaces are sporadic and not always there?

Comment: Well, what's the rule for extracting data then? In order to use a regular expression you need data that's at least mildly regular. If you can describe exactly what the extraction rules are in words, it would be easier to help you with the proper regex.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]","",x))` works. If you really like commas in your numbers, you could add that, for `^0-9.,` and forget about converting to numeric.

Comment: @Frank that worked beautifully! I don't know why I didn't think of that. I'd say that's a sufficient answer for the question given that it uses regex, so I'd suggest answering and I'll close this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using stringr and which should work if there's more than one number in your input (as long as the relevant amount is followed by some non-numeric text):

```
library("magrittr")
library("stringr")
amount <- badString %>%
  str_extract("(?<=AMT:\\s{0,20})[\\s0-9.,]+") %>%
  str_replace_all("[\\s,]", "")) %>%
  as.numeric
```

Note it assumes there will be 20 or fewer spaces between AMT: and the number; look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded length.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting the numeric part, you could subtract the non-numeric part:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]","",x))
```